# Importing my Apple Music library to Spotify

Tags: itunes, music, spotify

So I've been using iTunes for a while now and I have many songs from different sources:

1. Music I ripped from my CD collection, converted into mp3 and then imported to iTunes. Stored on my phone's SD card.
2. Music I bought from the iTunes Store, also stored on my phone's SD. Mostly in m4a format.
3. Music I added to my account with Apple Music, which means I haven't downloaded any file to my local  storage, just marked it with the "+" button in the app.

I recently discovered Spotify and though it may not have the whole catalog (so I heard) that Apple Music offers, it is certainly more friendly and I would bet that it has most of the music I listen to, so I would like to switch over there.

Thing is, I haven't found any reasonable way to migrate all my music to Spotify - I have never used playlists in iTunes nor in Apple Music, I just navigate through artists', albums' and songs' names, and I want my whole library (or whatever part of it which is available on Spotify) to move there.

I was thinking I could create a playlist which contains, essentially, my entire music collection, and then import that playlist. So I guess I'm asking these questions:

1. What's the easiest, fastest way I can compose a playlist in Apple Music/iTunes which includes all my music?
2. How can I import such playlist to Spotify?
3. As for my locally-stored music, does Spotify support playing these files and shuffling them with online-streaming music?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That is NOT how Spotify works.

Comment: Not sure why you were downvoted as the premise is reasonable, and Spotify does indeed permit local playback (and importing of playlists). I would (perhaps) remove or split your question about creating a playlist in iTunes into another question- it *may* that folks are judging that you've asked too many questions at once.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Spotify Supports Local Music

To address your last point first, Spotify does indeed support local music:

> In addition to over 30 million tracks that we offer, you can also use your Spotify app to play music files stored on your computer (which we call "local files").

From [*Local files*](https://support.spotify.com/us/using_spotify/features/listen-to-local-files/) feature explanation. To do so, you can:

> 1. Click **⌄** in the top-right corner of the app and select **Settings**.
> 2. Scroll down to **Local Files**.
> 3. Any files in My Music, Downloads, and iTunes folders are automatically selected. Switch off any sources you don't want Spotify to access.
> 4. Click **ADD SOURCE** to select another folder from which Spotify can access your personal music files.

### Apple Music Files

There are those who have managed to export their Apple Music as a playlist, then import that into Spotify, for example:

#### Soundiiz

> You can do it with **Soundiiz**.  Important: You have to download all the tracks in your AM playlist first.  Export it as a .m3u file.  Go to the Soundiiz website.  Login to your Spotify account.  Drag the .m3u file onto the tile that says "Drop here your file" Select Spotify as your destination platform.  Name and convert your playlist.
>
> Soundiiz will convert your playlist to Spotify and it will show up in your account, sometimes right away and sometimes you have to restart Spotfiy.  Soundiiz will also give you an error log letting you know what tracks it couldn't find.

From [repete7 on Spotify community](https://community.spotify.com/t5/Desktop-Mac-old/Returning-to-Spotify-from-Apple-Music-Can-I-bring-my-new-Apple/m-p/1185940/highlight/true#M3935).

#### Workflow

If you have an iDevice, you could use the [**Workflow** App](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/workflow/id915249334), which has a *'Add playlist to Spotify' workflow*.

#### Python

Lastly, [subzero2 has a solution involving python](https://community.spotify.com/t5/Desktop-Mac-old/Returning-to-Spotify-from-Apple-Music-Can-I-bring-my-new-Apple/m-p/3603703/highlight/true#M544469) on OSX:

> 1. In iTunes, export the playlist to a xml file and name it, say, `mylist.xml`
> 2. Copy the following code into a text editor and replace file name at the second line with the name of your xml file, say, `mylist.xml`.
> 3. Save this file a `.py` file to your desktop and name it, say, `extract_text.py`.  What this python file does is converting your xml file to a text file.

```py
#/bin/python
import re, io
f = io.open("change_this_to_the_name_of_your_exported_playlist.xml", mode="r", encoding="utf-8")
fout = io.open("output.txt", mode="w", encoding="utf-8")

l=[]
for line in f.readlines():
    match =  re.search("<key>(Name|Artist)</key><string>(.*?)</string>", line)
    if match:
        l.append(match.group(2))

for i in range(len(l)):
    song_or_artist = l[i].replace('&#38;','&') # XML formating replaces & with &#38; so we revert this replacement
    fout.write(song_or_artist + (u' - ' if i % 2 == 0 else u'\n'))
fout.close()
```

> 4. Open Mac OS X Terminal, paste the following command and hit Enter:

```
cd ~/Desktop
python extract_text.py
```

> 5. Then you will see a new file `output.txt` in your Desktop, which contains the song name and the artist name for each line.
> 6. Copy all the text inside to http://www.playlist-converter.net/ , and follow the instructions on the website to convert this text to your Spotify playlist!

Credit for the above to [subzero2](https://community.spotify.com/t5/user/viewprofilepage/user-id/16403791) of Spotify community, as above.